# How to weigh percentages with proc tabulate?

Tags: sas

I am creating a bunch of frequency tables using `proc tabulate`, and I have to weigh the percentage according to a set of weights regarding the age of each `person` in my dataset. My problem is that it seems like the weights have any impact on my results. I know, I can do this with proc freq, but my tables are pretty detailed, and therefore I am using proc tabulate.

I have included an example of a dataset, and what I have tried so far:

```
Data have; 
input gender wgt q1 year;
lines;
0  1.5  0  2014
0  1    1  2014
0  1.5  1  2014
0  1    1  2014
0  1.5  0  2014
1  1    1  2014
1  1    1  2014
1  1    1  2014
1  1    0  2014
1  1   1  2014
1  1    1  2014
;
run;

Proc format;
  value gender  0="boy";
                1= "girl";
  value q1f     0= "No"
                1="Yes";
run;

Proc tabulate data=have;
class gender q1 year;
weight wgt;
table gender*pctn<q1>, year*q1;
format gender gender. q1 q1f.;
run;
```

I know the results should be that app. `46,2 %` boys have answered "No" and app. 53,8 % have answered yes, when I include the weights, but the output from the proc tabulate gives me 40 % No and 60 % yes among the boys. 
What have I done wrong?

Comment: I don't know the `sas` language, but without weights, the output is correct because 3/5 boys voted yes (60%). So maybe you need need to do something like `table gender*pctn<q1*wgt>, year*q1`

Comment: To confirm - you're trying to produce something like this but using proc tabulate? `proc freq data = have;
  table gender * q1 /nocol nopercent nofreq;
  weight wgt;
  format gender gender. q1 q1f.;
run;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `WEIGHT` statement will affect `VAR` variable values, not the N count.  `PCT<N>` is a percentage of counts.  A 'FREQ' statement will affect the N count by causing internal repetition of a data point based on another variable, however FREQ does not work with fractional repetitions (values) and will round down.

From the helps

> **FREQ variable;**
>
> specifies a numeric variable whose value represents the frequency of the observation.  If you use the FREQ statement, then the procedure assumes that each observation represents n observations, where n is the value of variable.  If n is not an integer, then SAS truncates it. If n is less than 1 or is missing, then the procedure does not use that observation to calculate statistics.
>
> The sum of the frequency variable represents the total number of observations.

> **WEIGHT variable;**
>
> specifies a numeric variable whose values **weight the values of the analysis variables**.  The values of the variable do not have to be integers. PROC TABULATE responds to weight values in accordance with the following table.
>
> Weight Value: PROC TABULATE Response
>
> - 0 :  Counts the observation in the total number of observations
> - <0 : Converts the value to zero and counts the observation in the total number of observations
> - . : Excludes the observation

If you want to use a weight for pctN like counts, create a `unity` variable that is to be weighted and `PCTSUM`

```
Data have; 
input gender wgt q1 year;
unity = 1;
lines;
0  1.5  0  2014
0  1    1  2014
0  1.5  1  2014
0  1    1  2014
0  1.5  0  2014
1  1    1  2014
1  1    1  2014
1  1    1  2014
1  1    0  2014
1  1    1  2014
1  1    1  2014
;
run;

Proc tabulate data=have;
  title "Unity weighted";
  class gender q1 year;
  format gender gender. q1 q1f.;

  var unity;  %* <----------;
  weight wgt;

  table gender*unity, year*q1;  %* <---- debug, the count 'basis' for PCTSUM<q1> ;

  table gender*unity*(pctsum<q1>), year*q1;  %* <--- weighted unity PCTSUM;
run;
```